# 'you gonna be surprised' vs 'you're gonna be suprised'

Tags: future-tense

Can 'you gonna be surprised' be used instead of 'you're gonna be surprised'?

Google supports both almost equally:

- [You gonna be surprised](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you+gonna+be+surprised%22) (249k)
- [You're gonna be surprised](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you're+gonna+be+surprised%22) (258k)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*gonna* is informal and thus, those both sentences take liberty in sticking to the grammar rules defined.

> You gonna be surprised (even informal) = You're gonna be surprised.

Politely, *you are going to be (get) surprised!*